# Limit length of gridline (R plot)

Tags: r, plot

How can I make the gridlines in an R plot using `plot` to not extend beyond the plot's boundaries? i.e. need to define gridlines' origin and end.

On the example given, I want the gridlines drawn by `grid` and the gridline at y=7.5 drawn by `abline` to extend from the y-axis to the right edge of the box.

```
plot(1:10,1:10,type = "n")
abline(h = 7.5, v = 0, col = "gray60", lty = 3)
grid(10,10)
```

[image]

Comment: i cant reproduce this - the line stays within the bounding box.

Comment: I'll change to a simpler/clearer example just in case.

Comment: I also cant reproduce with this new example (unless I am misunderstanding what you want) - all lines are in the plot boundary box

Comment: @user20650 maybe is not clear - `abline(h = 7.5, v = 0, col = "gray60", lty = 3)` draws an "infinite" line at y=7.5.

Comment: @rnorouzian `xpd = FALSE` did it, at least with `abline`.
e.g. `abline(h = 7.5, v = 0, col = "gray60", lty = 3, xpd = FALSE)` here line at 7.5 stays within boundaries of plot.  It did not help with `grid`. Maybe its not possible. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe its related to the R version? I'm using R version 3.2.4 Revised (2016-03-16 r70336).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might have (unknowingly) set `xpd = TRUE` or `xpd = NA`. If you set your `xpd = FALSE` before your plot call, this will prevent your `grid` or `abline` (or ANY plot-additive object in Base R) from going beyond the plotting region.

So, do the following before your `plot()` call:

```
par(xpd = FALSE)
```

For your future plotting cases remember that `xpd = FALSE` can be both **locally** used within a command, like `abline(h = 2, xpd = FALSE)` or it can be used **globally**, like how I used it for your case.

Further remember that `xpd = NA` IS NOT the same as `xpd = FALSE`. The former allows plotting to go well beyond the plotting region to `par("oma")` (outer margin area), while the latter keeps everything within the `par("usr")` (inner plotting) region. These features are helpful in various visualizations in R.