# R gridlines and ablines extending beyond chart

Tags: r, time-series, rstudio

In RStudio I have recently found that my gridlines and ablines have suddenly extended beyond the boundaries of my time seriescharts. I am enclosing two charts with examples of these. They were well behaved previously so I am not sure if it is the code or some accidental change to settings in RStudio? Any ideas?

> [image: Ablines Example]
>   **Ablines Example**
>
> ---
>
> [image: Gridlines]
>   **Gridlines**

Comment: You probably have a `par()` graphics setting set somewhere that is meaning the lines are not being constrained to an individual plot. It is impossible to know for sure without knowing the code you are using.

Comment: perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44937209/limit-length-of-gridline-r-plot#comment76851588_44937209

Comment: in particular check `par("xpd")`

Comment: You nailed it Ben. I checked par("xpd") and returned NA. I have put in par(xpd = FALSE) before the plots and the grid/abline issue is now solved. Thank you very much Ben!

Comment: Thank you @thelatemail. This was helpful

Comment: @user20650, this question helped me understand the problem. Many thanks